# Jenkins Workflow Parallel Step and Joins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I am currently using the `parallel` build step in a Jenkins Workflow script where each branch make take a different amount of time.

```
parallel(fastBranch: {
    // Do something fast
}, slowBranch: { 
    // Do something slow
})
```

I've got a problem where I think maybe the `slowBranch` isn't completing because the `fastBranch` is quicker, is this possible? Is there any kind of join mechanism in the `parallel` step to ensure the next line isn't executed until all branches are complete.

Comment: The default behaviour is exactly like you would expect. The next step (after `parallel`) is reached when both branches finish.

You can modify this behaviour by using `failFast: true|false` as a `parallel` parameter: if `true` then the parallel step stops any execution of any branch just after one of them fails. But this is clearly not what you want.

Do you have more information? (stacktraces, logs, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is join. For this job:

```
parallel(fastBranch: {
    build("Test_fast")
}, slowBranch: { 
    build("Test_slow")
})
build("Test_join")
```

Log is:

```
parallel {
    Schedule job Test_fast
    Schedule job Test_slow
    Build Test_fast #1 started
    Build Test_slow #1 started
    Test_fast #1 completed 
    Test_slow #1 completed 
}
Schedule job Test_join
Build Test_join #1 started
Test_join #1 completed
```

Times are:

```
Fast Start:  17:06:00
Fast Finish: 17:06:01
Slow Start:  17:06:00
Slow Finish: 17:06:20
Join Start:  17:06:30
Join Finish: 17:06:30
```

Answer (score 0):

That should not be possible.  I use `parallel` for 25 parallel jobs, and they all complete at different times.  After all of them have finished execution, it will process any steps after the call to `parallel`.